# Making changes in already settled batches

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I currently am making a call to Authorize.net's API, and getting back settled batches. Now, to my understanding, once a batch is settled at the end of the day, I can't make any other changes to it.

For example, on Monday, someone buys something, but I forget to do the transaction (for whatever reason). On Tuesday, is there a way I can add that transaction to Monday's batch?

Answer (score 1):

No. Once a batch is settled you cannot modify it. But that shouldn't be a big deal since batches settle daily and that sale processed on Tuesday will be deposited in your account just one business day after Monday's batch.